# Modulus of $c^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

> For a positive real number $c$ and a complex number $z$, we define $c^z=e^{z\ln(c)}$. Express the modulus $|c^z|$ in terms of real and imaginary parts of $z$

I get $|c^z|=|e^{z\ln(c)}|=|e^{(x+iy)\ln(c)}|=|e^{x\ln(c)}||e^{iy\ln(c)}|=|c^x|\cdot 1=|c^x|$

and the imaginary part doesn't appear, did I do a mistake ?

Comment: The imaginary part appears in $\lvert e^{iy\ln (c)}\rvert$. And by the way, for $c > 0$, you have $c^x > 0$, so the modulus is unnecessary there. (Always assuming we use the real value of $\ln (c)$.)

Comment: No, your answer is correct. It just so happens that $|c^z|$ does not depend on $y$.

Comment: @Stefan yes, only the absolute value bars were too much, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$e^{iy\log c} = \cos (y\log c) + i\sin (y\log c)$$ and $\cos^{2}(\cdot) + \sin^{2}(\cdot) = 1.$